# C++ struct padding and field packing

Tags: c++, padding

Is there anything in the C++ standard preventing a compiler from packing its fields so that one field may overlap with the padding of another?

It's allowed when inheriting (possibly via the empty base class optimization). To illustrate the scenario, consider the following snippet:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>

struct A {
    A() { a2 = rand(); } // force non-POD
    uint32_t a1;
    uint16_t a2;
};

struct B {
    A b1;
    uint16_t b2;
};

struct C : A {
    uint16_t c;
};
```

`B` and `C` contain the same fields, but `C` will only occupy 8 bytes, whereas `B` will have padding inserted before `b2`.

I've tested this both with clang (Apple LLVM version 5.0) and GCC 4.7.3, they both behave the same, and produces the following layout:

```
struct A [8 Bytes]
    0: [uint32_t : 4] a1
    4: [uint16_t : 2] a2
   --- 2 Bytes padding ---                                                             

struct B [12 Bytes]
    0: [uint32_t : 4] b1.a1
    4: [uint16_t : 2] b1.a2
   --- 2 Bytes padding ---                                                             
    8: [uint16_t : 2] b2
   --- 2 Bytes padding ---                                                             

struct C [8 Bytes]
    0: [uint32_t : 4] A::a1
    4: [uint16_t : 2] A::a2
    6: [uint16_t : 2] c
```

(If `A` is made a POD, both `B` and `C` will have padding, presumably because `offsetof()` is allowed and the optimization would become visible and possibly break code).

I'm curious,  is there's a good reason for not packing the fields optimally in the `B` case?

Comment: `reason for not packing the fields optimally` optimally by which criteria?

Comment: Zdeslvav, size I guess.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Can you share how you can print those nice layouts with Clang and GCC? Thanks in advance :) (Side note: your example uses names from `std` without “`std::`” qualification nor using-declarations / using-directive; I guess that on your implementation `<cxxx>` happens to include `<xxx.h>` but that's not guaranteed.)

Comment: the layout is pulled out of the debug information. https://github.com/arvidn/struct_layout

Answer (score 4):

One `struct` will not overlap another `struct`, even if the elements of the `struct` that it overlaps are "padding".

Imagine this:

```
 A a;
 B x;
 memcpy(&x.b1, a, sizeof(a));
```

If `B` was "packed" so that `b2` is right next to the `a2` element in `A`, then it would get overwritten with whatever garbage is in `a` - which is probably not what the original author of such code would expect (I'm pretty sure the standard says that the above has to work).

However, your second example isn't a `struct` that contains another `struct`. It is a `struct` that inherits from another `struct`. In this case, the original `struct` A can not be used independently of the other `struct` member(s) (in this case `c`). The standard will have a section saying that copying a `struct` of type `A` over a `struct` of type `C` that inherits from `A` will be "undefined behaviour", allowing the compiler to "pack" in this case.

So these are two separate cases, which have different limitations.

Comment: +1 Likewise important, the size of a struct/class cannot be *less* than the size of its members, which is exactly what would happen if `b2` were packed into `b1`'s padding. It can be *greater* (due to structure padding of `B` members, duh), but it can never be less.

Comment: this is a good example. however, if A and B are non-PODS (or let's say non-standard layout), I would be surprised if the standard defines copying their bytes as well defined.

Comment: @WhozCraig I do seem to recall C guaranteeing sizeof() being at least the sum of sizeof() of all its members. However, it's not obvious that this rule is necessary or makes sense for non-standard layout types (where offsetof is not allowed for instance).

Comment: Although A is a "non-POD" type, doesn't mean that it is allowed to break standard rules for `struct` - `sizeof(A)` should still be the same as `sizeof(B::b1)`, for example.

Comment: yeah. This may be the part of the standard that enforces this behavior. However, I can't think of a good reason for the standard to provide such guarantee (keep in mind we're talking about non-standard layout types). C++98, presumably, had the opportunity to not provide it (again, for non-POD types).

Comment: The standard may well have the opportunity, but there are several reasons why I see it as "it's not going to happen":
1. It adds another special case to the compiler - compilers are awfully complex as it is, with out adding further to their complexity. 
2. It's a pretty "limited market" - in other words, the gains vs extra compiler complexity is quite small (and of course, in some cases, it may not even work correctly, if you take it to extremes - e.g. if b2 is a uint32_t instead of uint16_t)

Answer (score 1):

`I'm curious, is there's a good reason for not packing the fields optimally in the B case?`

In this case, compiler makes sure that types fit on 4-byte boundaries (alignment is [typically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) a [performance](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/) [optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086656/bit-aligning-for-space-and-performance-boosts)). Therefore it ensures that `sizeof(A)` is 8 bytes. If it would pack `B` to only take 8 bytes, this means that `sizeof(b1)` would have to be 6, thus `sizeof(b1) != sizeof(A)` which wouldn't make sense.

The reason why `sizeof(b1)` equals `sizeof(A)` is that `sizeof` operator doesn't evaluate the expression - it is evaluated at compile time, thus it operates on type of expression `b1` which is `A`.

This means that you would end up with following:

```
B b;
sizeof(b.b1); // => 8, as b1 type is B
sizeof(b);    // => 8 (although b consists of b1 and c);
```

When you inherit C from A, it is completely new type, so compiler can align it as needed.

Comment: It's not entirely obvious to me that it doesn't make sense. In a world of C++ and non-standard layout, it's not obvious that these properties need to be exposed to the programmer.

Comment: for sure having an instance with different size than its type is not something that makes much sense?

Comment: I think that depends on what you expect to conclude from the return value of sizeof(). My understanding is that non-standard layout types do not expose anything about their layout. It doesn't seem that far fetched that they also wouldn't provide those kinds of guarantees about sizeof() of their members. What can one use sizeof() on a non-standard layout type for other than allocating storage for it?

Comment: What `sizeof` returns is defined by C++ standard. There are no standard and non-standard layouts, they are all compliant with C++ spec or the compiler is broken. `sizeof` can be used for other things: implementing some compile time checks, implementing `countof`, etc.

Comment: c++11 defines the term "standard layout" as essentially the layout constraints of a POD type. I have still not been able to find a place in the standard that requires this padding behavior. sizeof is not particularly strictly defined on non primitive types. I'm just looking in the c++ standard though, maybe it's inherited from C? It does say explicitly that sizeof(A) does not have to be the amount of space used by the base class when C derives from it, in footnote 77.

Comment: padding behavior is an implementation detail. The reason stems from the fact that `sizeof(t) == sizeof(T)`, as defined by standard. As I explained in the answer, if it was like you suggested, the result would be that an object consisting of `A` and `uint_16` has the same size as `A`. Compiler did the right thing: it decided that `A` takes 8 bytes, as it is free to do so, usually due to performance reasons. This means that `b1` instance of `A` in `B` must also take 8 bytes. Any additional member of B thus results in `B` being large than 8.

Comment: if it's more performant to pad (which I doubt), presumably the compiler would have done so in ``C`` as well. If the behavior is implementation defined (is that what you're saying?) then the compiler _could_ have packet struct ``B`` as well, but it chose not to (presumably for no apparently good reason). I cannot find support in the standard for your statement "This means that ``b1`` instance in ``A`` in ``B`` must also take 8 bytes". In fact, it explicitly allows this not to be the case for base classes.

Comment: I have added links to perf argument: compiler doesn't know exactly on which CPU the code will run, and for many CPUs this boosts perf. I have also extended the explanation why `sizeof(t) == sizeof(T)` given that `T` is the type of expression `t`, thus size of b1 must equal size of A -> 8 bytes. Of course that compiler would pad C - just add an `uint16_t` member to C and it will grow to 12 bytes, not 10. You are mistaking by assuming that compiler would align every member on 4 byte boundary - but it is free to pick its optimizations, including the trade-off between perf and memory consumption.

Comment: I find it hard to believe this padding would ever provide performance benefits. if anything it will put more load on the L1 cache (all fields are correctly aligned when packed). you keep making the assertion that a field must use up as much storage as its sizeof() (for non-POD types), but without a link to a paragraph in the standard it doesn't carry much weight. I'm not assuming any compiler would always align fields to 4 bytes, that would clearly not be a good idea. padding is implementation defined, and as far as I can tell, the compiler could choose not to pad in the case of ``B``.

Comment: I gave the links to theory and experiments about perf - feel free to choose what you want to believe. field storage == sizeof(T) is defined by 3.2.4, 3.9 (particularly point 4), 3.9.1 and 5.3.3 (in ISO 14882), just not in the form that you expect. (see object representation, how it differs from value representation and how it is related to sizeof). `sizeof` would be useless if instances of T would take different amount of memory than sizeof(T).

Comment: it sounds like you're implying the ``c`` field is misaligned, which it clearly isn't. When padding is added to the end of ``T``, an instance _does_ use less memory than ``sizeof(T)``. I would love to hear about an example of valid use of sizeof that would break if case ``B`` was packed. There is no section 3.2.4 in ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E) afaict, section 3.2 describes ODR. 3.9 can certainly be interpreted as any instantiation of a type ``T`` must use ``sizeof(T)`` bytes. It would seem like a crack in the class abstraction though.

Comment: I am not implying that. To me it makes perfect sense. Instance doesn't use less than `sizeof(T)` you are confusing  object representation with value representation.

Comment: my understanding of what you're saying is that 3.9 p4 "The object representation of an object of type T is the sequence of N unsigned char objects taken up by the object of type T, where N equals sizeof(T)" forces each member of a class to use sizeof(T) bytes, preventing packing. There doesn't seem to be an obvious good reason for the standard to mandate this. Since subclasses can omit their padding, you can still not assume that the trailing padding of a type exists (in whatever way you could assume that without invoking undefined behavior).